# Check whether the following first order Differential Equation is linear

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $(y^2-1)dx+xdy=0$

When I consider $x$ as  independent and $y$ as dependent variable then,

$${dy\over dx}={(1-y^2)\over x}$$ which is clearly not linear.

When I consider $y$ as  independent and $x$ as dependent variable then,

$${dx\over dy}={-x\over y^2-1}$$ but as ${1\over y^2-1}$ is not continuous, it is not linear. Can I say that it is linear on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$

Can someone please go through what I have written.

Thanks.

Comment: How taking $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$ will make $1/(y^2-1)$ continuous ?

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$$ (y^2-1)\frac{dx}{dy}+x=0 $$

is a linear combination of $x$ and its derivative $\frac{dx}{dy}$ where the coefficients are constants or functions of $y$. So the equation is linear.